# Pandas: memory usage when working with very many columns using Groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with over 1000 columns and I would like to know whether it makes a difference on memory usage and/or speed to run a groupby directly on a dataframe or to create a smaller subset of the dataframe columnwise.

```
df[['xnew','ynew','znew']] = df.groupby(['a','b'])['x','y','z'].transform(lambda f: f.rolling(3).mean().shift())
```

or,

```
df2=df[['a','b','x','y','z']]
df2[['xnew','ynew','znew']] = df2.groupby(['a','b'])['x','y','z'].transform(lambda f: f.rolling(3).mean().shift())
df=pd.concat([df,df2[['xnew','ynew','znew']]],axis=1)
```

I would like to test this myself but I am unfamiliar with how to do it. Advice on how to test this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, it doesn't matter on either dimension. From a Colab notebook:

[image]

```
%load_ext memory_profiler
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'a': [1]*100 + [2]*100, 'b': [3]*50 + [4]*50 + [5]*50 + [6]*50}
for i in range(1000):
    d[i] = np.random.random(200)
for c in 'xyz':
    d[c] = np.random.random(200)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

%time %memit df[['xnew','ynew','znew']] = df.groupby(['a','b'])[['x','y','z']].transform(lambda f: f.rolling(3).mean().shift())

%%time 
%%memit
df2=df[['a','b','x','y','z']]
df2[['xnew','ynew','znew']] = df2.groupby(['a','b'])[['x','y','z']].transform(lambda f: f.rolling(3).mean().shift())
df=pd.concat([df,df2[['xnew','ynew','znew']]],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this is to get the time and then subtract the time at the end of the process to display the elapsed time.

```
import time

start = time.time()
# Write down the process.
process_time = time.time() - start

print(process_time)
```